# Absolute positioning and z-index for nested element

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I have a deeply nested custom dropdown menu (.options) which I would like to be shown on top of everything else, but positioned relative to its parent. However, if this happens to be near the bottom of my page, the footer will always be drawn on top of it. I can't seem to figure out to get this deeply nested menu to always show on top.

```css
.item {
    position: relative;
}
.options {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-example">
    <div class="list">
        <ul>
            <li class="item"><a href="#" onclick="toggleOptionsMenu();">Click here to see options</a>
                <ul class="options">
                    <li>Option 1</li>
                    <li>Option 2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        Everything here will always show on top of this options list
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include your existing CSS too, so we can see what the problem is.

Comment: What's happening now? Can you provide a Snippet?

Comment: I'm guessing the footer's z-index is greater than the drop-down menu. You need to make the drop-down menu to have higher z-index.

Comment: @Mike the problem is that your absolutely positioned element is inside its own stacking context. So no matter how big you set your z-index, it will still be overlapped. Set `position: relative;` on `.my-example` instead.

Comment: Thank you @TylerH

Comment: As Tyler mentioned the problem is your position: absolute in the .options. When you add a background: red, you'll see that the options box is upon all other elements.

Comment: But there's probably a better dupe somewhere...